# SMTP DATE command purpose?

Tags: smtp

I am looking at my SMTP logs. The script I just run tells me that one of our mail servers has sent 19848kb, and received 386kb. This is pretty weird as this server should just be forwarding on mail that it received.

One of the sources out outbound traffic I noticed is for lines to do with the DATE command. For instance, this line:

```
11/16/11 00:26:57   SMTP-OU 8AA56F43369C40ECBE07D7A805617D74.MAI    1184    [ipAddress] DATE        250 2.0.0 OK 1321403130 v50si13351192wec.51 172503  45
```

`DATE` is the command. `250 2.0.0 OK 1321403130 v50si13351192wec.51` is the response to the command. `172503` is the number of bytes sent, and `45` is the number of bytes received.

I can't find the specification of what this command does. Is it something like `Data-extended`? It can't be transmitting just the calender-date, because it is too big for that.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you specify which SMTP software you use and include the full log of a single transaction and not a single line. Also, this is a serverfault question, it has nothing to do with coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no DATE command in SMTP. I guess they are using this word only in the log, to mark the second part of the DATA conversation. I mean the fist part is: 
DATA
354 go on

The second part is:
... the actual data ...
250 OK

Comment: 250 ok is a response from the SMTP server.  Certainly you're correct in that there is no `DATE` command in SMTP or ESMTP.